# How to create similar multiple forms using a button?

Tags: forms, 9

I am using Drupal 9. I am creating a module that has a form with a button that will re-create another form similar to the first one.

These is my code.

```php
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $database = \Drupal::database();
  $result = $database->select('user_details', 'u')
    ->fields('u', ['uid']);
  $row = $result->execute()->fetchAll();
  $rowCount = count($row);

  $form['buttons_multiple'] = [
    '#type' => "container",
    '#attributes' => ['style' => 'margin-top: 2em;'],
    'add_chat' => [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Add form +'),
      '#attributes' => [
        'style' => 'font-size: 1.2em;',
      ],
      '#submit' => ['::addForm'],
    ],
  ];

  for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $rowCount; $counter++) {
    $form['form_box_' . $counter] = [
      '#type' => "container",
      'full_name'.$counter => [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => 'name',
        '#size' => 12,
        '#required' => TRUE,
      ],
      'buttons_single' => [
        '#type' => "container",
        'save'.$counter => [
          '#type' => 'submit',
          '#value' => $this->t('Save'),
          '#attributes' => [
            'style' => 'font-size: 1em;',
          ],
          '#submit' => ['::submitForm'],
        ],
      ],
      'count' => [
        '#type' => 'hidden',
        '#value' => $counter,
      ],
    ];
  }
}

public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  $name = $form_state->getValue('full_name');
  $counter =  $form_state->getValue('count');
        
  $form_state->set('user_values', [
    'name' => $form_state->getValue('name'),
  ]);

  // For testing purpose. Display full name
  $this->messenger()->addMessage($this->t('Hi, your name is %name.', ['%name' => $name]));
}

public function addForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $values = [
    [
      'full_name' => '',
    ],
  ];
    
  $database = \Drupal::database();
  $query = $database->insert('user_details')->fields(['full_name']);
  foreach ($values as $details) {
    $query->values($details);
  }
  $query->execute();
}
```

Based on the code above, I only get the name of the last added form even if I clicked the saved button of the first form.

How will I work on the saved button for each form?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In Drupal 7, this was done with hook_forms(), but that was removed in Drupal 8. You can use the replacement method: https://www.drupal.org/node/2188851

Comment: @Jaypan, thank you for this article. It helps me a lot.